# Webpack config error: options has an unknown property 'modules[localIdentName]'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4, css-loader

I'm getting the following error output when I try to run webpack:

```
ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'modules[localIdentName]'.
```

I'm currently using `"css-loader": "^3.5.3"` and here is my [webpack.config.js](https://github.com/ethanwilkins/portfolio/blob/master/webpack.config.dev.js).

Comment: They changed the API [options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-loader#options). Try using `localsConvention` instead of `localIdentName`.

Comment: @MattCarlotta This returns the same error. I believe localsConvention and localIndentName are for two different purposes as well.

Comment: Looking at your configuration closely, it looks like you're using some outdated plugins/configurations. For example, the CRA no longer supports `proxy` options in the `package.json` and `UglifyJsPlugin` has been mostly replaced by [TerserWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/). In addition, you're creating a webpack configuration that is already supported by the [CRA's react-scripts](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet).

Comment: @MattCarlotta Thank you very much! Removing webpack and updating react-scripts enabled me to use CSS Modules.